# Error when get content in CKEditor with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea cols="80" id="content" name="content" rows="10">html format here</textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<div id="data"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'content');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var content = $('#content');
        alert(content);
        //$('#data').html(content);
    });          
});  
</script>
```

> When I alert(content) is result is error, can't get value html, how to fix it ?

Comment: what is this? var content = $('#content'); you can not do this this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a div as a whole like this

```
var content = $('#content'); //wrong way
alert(content);
```

You can alert a div's content by changing your code like this:

```
var content = $('#content').html(); //correct way
alert(content);
```

EDIT:

to get value use:

```
var content = $('#content').value(); //correct way for getting an element's value
alert(content);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use CKEditor, can not get value from textarea

Comment: content is id of your text area?

Comment: check the updated answer. try using var content = $('#content').value(); Hopefully this will return the value of your textarea.